# What are the practical problems with radial menus?

Tags: user-interface, menu, user-experience

Years ago I discovered radial menus and realized that they could potentially be much easier to use than linear menus. At the time, I didn't have enough understanding of user experience principles (other than Fitt's law) to give them an honest evaluation. I thought that if they were indeed much easier to use in practice they should eventually show up in mainstream products, even against the inertia of the convention of linear menus.

Fast forward to today, I download [ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html) to visualize some graphs. It uses a radial context menu and I realize that these things really *are* easier to use, especially when you learn the simple mouse gestures to select nested menus.

Why hasn't the radial menu gained more traction? Is it user inertia? Framework inertia (i.e. not enough good implementations on various platforms)? Are they just not *that* much better in practice, overall?

Comment: You may have better luck with this over at the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) SE site.  In fact [the very first question on the site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-radial-contextual-menus-better-than-vertical-list-menus) is about radial menus.

Answer (score 1):

In UX there are things we can do and some we would like to do but don't. Understanding how the human machine ingests information is critical in designing a great experience. A radial menu does make sense but it's not what a user has been accustom to. It's not impossible to implement but it will take the user some time to understand the context of where they were to where they are now. There are inherent behavioral patterns that can't be swept aside. You learn to push the boundaries and still make it usable just beyond the visual appeal.